# Coredata/sqlite to Realm for Xcode application

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, realm, realm-migration

I have sqlite database in my application, but now i want to switch to realm. How can i use Realm instead of Sqlite??

Comment: You want to use both Realm and Sqlite int your app? I assume not but your question is very unclear.

Comment: Realm instead of Sqlite @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Then the answer must be: yes of course you can but we can't tell you how because your question is way to broad.